# memory leak in valgrind c++

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory

I tested my code on valgrind. It said I lost 1 block in memory leak, which is in this line :
Project *temp = new Project[numProjects + 1]; . Does anyone now how to fix the issue.

```
Project *temp = new Project[numProjects + 1];
```

```
bool Department::addProject(Project &newProject)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        double totalCost = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numProjects; i++)
        {
            totalCost += projects[i].m_cost;
        }
        totalCost += newProject.m_cost;
        if (totalCost > budget)
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Project *temp = new Project[numProjects + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < numProjects; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = projects[i];
            }
            temp[numProjects] = newProject;
            numProjects++;
            delete[] projects;
            projects = temp;
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

I tried many ways including delete[] temp or delete temp inside for if and else and even clear() function after that. Nothing changes the equation.

Comment: Can you share declaration of the Project class definition?